# Pandas groupby and create a unique ID column for every row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DF:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([["apple",1],["apple",20],["apple",21],["mango",31],["mango",17]])
df.columns = ["fruit", "count"]
df
```

OP:

```
    fruit   count
0   apple   1
1   apple   20
2   apple   21
3   mango   31
4   mango   17
```

I am trying to create a new column which creates `unique_row_id, for each row` within `each group`. For example for the group `apple` the `unique` column should have entries `0,1,2` since there are 3 rows and for  group `mango` it should be `0,1` as there are 2 rows

```
df["unique_row_number_per_group"] =df.reset_index().groupby("fruit")["index"].transform(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
```

OP:

```
f   ruit    count   unique_rows_per_group
0   apple   1        0
1   apple   20       1
2   apple   20       2
3   mango   31       0
4   mango   17       1
```

This works but takes horribly long for big DFs, any suggestion on doing this a more pandas efficient way will be helpful

Comment: [groupby cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) -> `df["unique_row_number_per_group"] = df.groupby("fruit").cumcount()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need count per group by row we have `cumcount`:

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('fruit').cumcount()
df
Out[346]: 
   fruit  count  new
0  apple      1    0
1  apple     20    1
2  apple     21    2
3  mango     31    0
4  mango     17    1
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = df.assign(new=1).groupby('fruit')['new'].cumsum()-1
df
Out[352]: 
   fruit  count  new
0  apple      1    0
1  apple     20    1
2  apple     21    2
3  mango     31    0
4  mango     17    1
```